# Access div within Polymer callback function

Tags: javascript, polymer, google-visualization, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I have a basic Polymer app setup (one of the sample applications with 3 views in a drawer). I am trying to dynamically display Google Charts within each view. I load google charts in the Polymer ready() function and pass in a function on the setOnLoadCallback. In the callback function I try and create the chart and add it to a div, but am unable to find the div. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

```
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',
      ready: function() {
        console.log('Polymer ready');

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawBasic);
      },

      drawBasic : function() {
        console.log('preparing to create chart');

        var chart_div = this.$.chart_div;
        console.log(chart_div);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your mistake is here:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawBasic)
```

One way to fix this is using `bind` method. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) you can find documentation about that method. So, I suppose this will work:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawBasic.bind(this))
```